# How can i mock this method in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit4

I am new to the mockito framework, Can anyone help me with how to mock this method.

```
@Override
    public Device getCurrentDevice() {
        return getDeviceById(Device.getCurrentDeviceId());
    }
```

When this method is called, The normal flow is to return a null object, but I want it to return another value for example new Device(). How would I do that?

Also should i use mock() or spy(), because this method will be called multiple times in the test and each time i want it to return mCurrentDevice?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

My unit test:

```
KitConfiguration kitConfiguration = ServerDocProcessor.processKitConfigResponse(kitJson);
    kitConfiguration.initialize();
    ScoutDevice mCurrentDevice = new ScoutDevice();
    Mockito.mock(KitConfiguration.class);
Mockito.when(kitConfiguration.getCurrentDevice()).thenReturn(mCurrentDevice);
    mScoutDeviceManager.setDeviceProvider(kitConfiguration);
```

The kitconfiguration.getCurrentDevice() method is called in the last line.

this is the error I get:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.


    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:495)
    at com.resatech.android.core.scout.ScoutDeviceManagerTest.onDeviceConnectStateChangeTestAsMaster(ScoutDeviceManagerTest.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Please show full unit test code

Comment: @ShaluTD. Updated. Please see now

Answer (score 0):

this part goes in to `@Before` method:

```
KitConfiguration kitConfiguration;

   @Before
   void setup() {
       kitConfiguration = Mockito.mock(KitConfiguration.class);
   }
```

and in each test method you can mock return value like this:

```
 @Test
    void yourTest() {
        Mockito.when(kitConfiguration.getCurrentDevice()).thenReturn(mCurrentDevice);
        
        // do test here
    }
```

and make your KitConfiguration.java public

Comment: I updated the question with error logs. and KitConfiguration is public

Comment: make KitConfiguration public

Comment: It is public, Any other suggestion ?

Comment: See updated answer. You don't need to initialize  kitConfiguration just mock it.

Comment: No im initializing it for other values, I have provided and gotten all other values except for this one method, since this method (getCurrentDevice()) calls a static method of another class , that's why I just want it to return my own value. 

Am I doing something wrong if I want to mock just one method of that class, while the rest of class gives me result as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to another answer you need to use a **Spy**. Spy lets you to create an instance of some class that is exactly as created with `new` but in addition you can override its functionality. Usage is like:

```
@Spy
private KitConfiguration kitConfiguration;
```

above makes a new instance of class and makes Mockito aware of it. Below has all the other init stuff you might want to do.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    kitConfiguration = ServerDocProcessor.processKitConfigResponse(kitJson);
    kitConfiguration.initialize();
}
```

You can mock one type of method call with:

```
Mockito.when(kitConfiguration.getCurrentDevice())
            .thenReturn(mCurrentDevice);
```

and the rest of the functionality of `kitConfiguration` will function normally.